# Regional pricing

Tags: expresso-store

My client would like to increase prices by 20% for some countries. The reason for this is that they want to show a product at £25 inclusive of tax if it's a UK delivery, £25 with no tax if it's a USA delivery.

Is there a way to achieve this using Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justin said this is basically how Store 2 behaves already.

The price you enter for each product is the price that is displayed on your site. You can then set up a tax rate for 20% for the UK and mark it as "included in price". This means all orders with a shipping address in the UK will see a 20% tax (though their order total will not increase).

All orders outside the UK will still be charged the same price, but they will not see any line items for tax included in their order.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I had seen that option but had misunderstood how it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

In Store 2 you can determine if you want the price to be tax-inclusive or not. If you choose to have the prices as tax-inclusive you will simply need to enter £25 for the price and Store will determine the taxable amount based upon the users location. For this to work properly though you will need to either set a default location for new carts or have the user enter their country to assign it to the cart.